# Windows 10 custom startup/login/unlock sounds not playing correctly

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, system-sounds

I am running the latest version of Windows 10 (clean install + update a few days ago), and I am trying to set my startup/shutdown, login/logoff, and unlock sounds to be the windows XP startup and shutdown sound (because I am a nerd, and they make me happy). I have followed a bunch of different tutorials to try to accomplish this, all pretty much saying the same thing. Basically, I have tried the following:

1. Run Registry Editor and change:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsLogon\ExcludeFromCPL from 1 to 0
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsLogoff\ExcludeFromCPL from 1 to 0
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsUnlock\ExcludeFromCPL from 1 to 0

2. Opened sound preferences window, and gone to the "Sounds" tab.

- Checked the box labeled "play Windows Startup sound"
- Under program events, selected "Windows logon" and then browse to select the XP logon.wav file in my documents. Upon clicking the test button, it works. I click apply and repeat this for the logoff and unlock sounds.

When starting the machine, the windows 7 (not XP, what I would like) startup sound plays when I get to the login view, and that's it. There is no sound if I sleep and then unlock, nor any sound when I logoff/shutdown.

Next, I tried replacing all of the native windows sound files that I am trying to modify with the XP ones. I found three directories containing the sounds that need to change:

- C:\Windows\Media
- C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-shell-sounds_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_a398148b5fe0ca58
- C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-shell-sounds_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.122_none_8430d41e1480ba73

**From my understanding, the second two might be different for different people. A post on tom's hardware told me to search for "WinSxS" https://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2754414/change-windows-startup-sound.html

For each of these directories, I did the following:

1. Right-click, properties. Security tab. Advanced button. Change the owner to my name. Okay. Okay. Back to the security tab. Edit permissions. Grant administrators full access. Click "yes" on the popup. Get two more popups:

- One "Windows Security", and one "Error Applying Security"; [image: First/second popup]
  I click cancel on the second one, triggering this:[image: Third popup]

Then Okay, and cancel on both popups.

2. Delete the files:

- "Windows Unlock.wav"
- "Windows Startup.wav"
- "Windows Shutdown.wav"
- "Windows Logon.wav"
- "Windows Logoff Sound.wav"

3. Copy the files (with the same names) into the directory.
4. Repeat this for all three directories mentioned above.

Again, exactly the same result as above; only sound out of turning on/off my computer and logging out/in and unlocking is the windows 7 startup sound when the login screen is reached.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've tried to do this before, and unfortunately I had no success. I too miss the logon sounds. Windows removed a huge part of their heritage by getting rid of them. I still get a rush whenever I log on to XP!

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already heard this one before, but Windows has unfortunately removed the logon/logoff sounds because if they had kept them, they would have had to rewrite the entire PlaySound API, and for "Performance reasons".